# How can I convert "21-05-26 12:26:00.824000000 AMERICA/TORONTO" into format "2021-05-26T12:26:00.824Z"?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have tried like this but its not working.

```
with
  inputs (ts) as (
    select '21-05-26 12:26:00.824000000 AMERICA/TORONTO' from dual 
  )
select to_timestamp_tz(ts,
                       'Dy Mon dd hh24:mi:ss TZD yyyy TZR',
                       'nls_date_language = english') as ts
from   inputs
;
```

Comment: Your format doesn't match your input string value. But aside from that, if the input represents 12:26 in Toronto local time,. do you really want the (string) output as 12:26 UTC? Or do you want the UTC equivalent of that Toronto time?

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your input string to a timestamp with timezone value with:

```
select to_timestamp_tz(ts, 'RR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZR') as ts from inputs
```

As your input string only has two digits for the year you can use [YY or RR](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-6C75461E-2E18-4C35-9EB4-038A7E1C9C1F); the latter tends to be appropriate but it depends on your data. Ideally you would have 4-digit years to avoid the issue. You don't need to specify the language here, as you don't have any day or month names; it doesn't hurt but doesn't do anything. Time zone names are not NLS-dependent.

Your client or application will then format that for display, usually with the session NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT setting. If you want a string result in that particular format you can explicitly convert back to a string with:

```
select to_char(
  to_timestamp_tz(ts, 'RR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZR'),
  'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"') as ts
from inputs ;

2021-05-26T12:26:00.824Z
```

The `"T"` and `"Z"` parts are [character literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-EAB212CF-C525-4ED8-9D3F-C76D08EEBC7A).

However, 'Z' indicates UTC times, so perhaps you should be converting the Toronto time to UTC with `at UTC`:

```
select to_char(
  to_timestamp_tz(ts, 'RR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZR') at time zone 'UTC',
  'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"') as ts
from inputs ;

2021-05-26T16:26:00.824Z
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0612d5d7a36cff499edc843b8e91ba81)

But you should only convert to a string for display; if you are storing the value you should keep it as a proper timestamp, timestamp with time zone or timestamp with local time zone, as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly do you want: your topic's heading says about converting to formatted string, but in the topic's body you are asking about converting to timestamp...
So I showed both:

```sql
with inputs (ts) as ( select '21-05-26 12:26:00.824000000 AMERICA/TORONTO' from dual ) 
select 
  v.*,
  to_char((string_to_timestamp at time zone 'UTC'),'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssxff3"Z"') timestamp_to_char_UTC
from (
select 
  ts, -- < string
  to_timestamp_tz(ts, 'yy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ssxff TZR', 'nls_date_language = english') as string_to_timestamp
from inputs 
) v;

TS                                          STRING_TO_TIMESTAMP                            TIMESTAMP_TO_CHAR_UTC
------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------- -------------------------
21-05-26 12:26:00.824000000 AMERICA/TORONTO 2021-05-26 12:26:00.824000000 AMERICA/TORONTO  2021-05-26T16:26:00.824Z
```

Comment: Ignoring the time zone `AMERICA/TORONTO` and just adding `Z` (which indicates UTC time) returns wrong times. `12:26:00` at `AMERICA/TORONTO` is not `12:26:00` at  `UTC`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit ah, didn't know that Z is a timezone synonym (it's Zulu in /usr/share/zoneinfo, not Z), but oracle doesn't know even about Zulu, just UTC or 0..

Comment: fixed the query

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov - the requested output format is ISO-8601, [which uses Z to designate UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)). It isn't an Oracle thing.

Comment: @AlexPoole I know, but TZR is not Oracle's thing either... They use official timezone names and regions, but unfortunately oracle doesn't use timezone files from OS, but uses own TZ files with timezones data which we need to upgrade each time (`V$TIMEZONE_FILE`)